# Creating a SQL computed column in a Dynamics 365 View

Tags: sql, microsoft-dynamics

I want to create a view with a computed column which returns:
-Either DirPerson.Name if it is not null
OR
-DirPartyTable.Name if the other one is null

Both tables are joined in my view via the HCMWorkerTable:
[image]

I added the following computed column:
[image]

This gives me the following SQL:
[image]

1.Why is my computed column resulting in a CAST instead of a CASE Statement? What is wrong with my syntax?
2.Why is SQL using CROSS JOINS with WHERE? (relations are specified as INNER JOINS)